# Swift - Space Invaders (Aliens Display Loop Not Working)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently trying to make a space invaders game, I've got my ship movement working and am currently working on my Alien Display loop.
I'm close but for some reason my screen keeps coming up blank, no aliens are being displayed. Can anyone help? Here's what I have so far.

```
//Add and display given amount of aliens...
    while displayAliens == true {
        aliens.append(SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ClassicAlien")))
        self.addChild(aliens[displayLoopCounter])
        //Location
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x = 0
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.y = 0
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x = CGFloat(displayLoopCounter + 25)
        displayLoopCounter += 1
        //Have we run out of aliens yet?
        if displayLoopCounter > alienAmount {
            displayAliens = false
        }

}
}
```

Comment: perhaps try setting position before calling addChild

Comment: Thank you, but the bug is still persisting. I was thinking there might be something wrong with my loops logic.

Comment: I posted a better loop below. Do you know where the origin of your view is? Is 0,0 the middle of the view or is it the top left? Perhaps set x and y to a test value of 25,25 and see what happens.

Comment: I dabbled with your loop, the origin of 0,0 will be set to the middle of the screen. I've gotten my image to display but I still can't get a proper set up of even spacing between the aliens across the screen. Thanks for your help, if you have any more advice, please let me know.

Comment: What's the spacing issue? Also, are you trying to have only one horizontal line, or a multiple vertical rows as well? I would need more info to help you further. P.s. would also appreciate if you accepted the answer if your display problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not %100 sure where the issue is, but your loop would be cleaner as :

```
//Add and display given amount of aliens...
    while (alienAmount >= displayLoopCounter) {
        aliens.append(SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ClassicAlien")))
        self.addChild(aliens[displayLoopCounter])

   //Location
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.y = 0
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x = CGFloat(displayLoopCounter + 25)
        displayLoopCounter += 1

    }
```